# Why does my Google Home send an empty location field in an Actions On Google webhook request?

Tags: actions-on-google, google-home

I have been following the [template on GitHub](https://github.com/actions-on-google/dialogflow-name-psychic-nodejs) for integration with the locations API the Actions On Google offers.

It works fine in the simulator and even on the Google Assistant for Phones, i.e. I either get a lat/lon pair or a coarse location provided depending on whether the device has a screen or not.

However, on my physical Google Home device, the location field in the response is empty and I cannot figure out why.

In one step, I request the permission with

```
app.askForPermission(Responses.permissionReason(), app.SupportedPermissions.DEVICE_COARSE_LOCATION);
```

In my follow-up step I then check if the permission was granted and continue:

```
if (!app.isPermissionGranted()) {
  return Promise.reject(new Error('Permission not granted'));
}
const location = app.getDeviceLocation();
```

If I start this conversation from my Google Home, however, `getDeviceLocation` is `undefined`.

Looking at the request, the permission is clearly granted but the location field is empty:

```
<snip>
"user": {
    "userStorage": "{\"data\":{}}",
    "lastSeen": "2018-01-20T10:50:01Z",
    "permissions": [
        "DEVICE_COARSE_LOCATION"
    ],
    "locale": "en-GB",
    "userId": "<redacted>"
},
"device": {
    "location": {}
},
</snip>
```

Full request [here](https://gist.github.com/passy/937aa2a50b87ccb9b2791a3b19962218).

I couldn't find any information in the documentation about why this would happen. Could someone fill me in?

Comment: Have you tried using `DEVICE_PRECISE_LOCATION` yet? this works fine for me on both phones and the Google Home.

Comment: I was under the impression that `DEVICE_PRECISE_LOCATION` was not available for Google Homes at all. If it is, I could probably go with it, but it would be a bit unfortunate as I don't really need that level of precision.

Answer (score 2):

Check to make sure that your Google Home has a location set for it in the configuration. If you have configured it for voice recognition, make sure it is your voice being recognized and not a generic account.

Comment: I do have a home location set for it and an account linked. Other built-in services like locations and travel time also work just fine.

Comment: I noticed that even though the before mentioned services worked and "Hey Google, what's my home address?" gave the expected answer, asking "Hey Google, where am I?" would tell me that there was no location set and asked me to provide an address. Trying to provide an address would always end up with an error, however. I then found a menu inside the "Home" app that allowed me to provide one and after waiting for a day (rebooting was not enough), I now have an address in the payload.